# Change from personal to organizational Account in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

we are using Microsoft Azure DevOps with personal accounts (with company mail-adress). Last month our company switched to Azure-AD and we want to use the companyaccounts to login in AzureDevOps.
Is there any way to link/change or migrate our private accounts to the new ones?

Comment: Does my answer can give you any help?Feel free to let us know the latest state about your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**, confirm the org you located has been back with AAD. To check this, go **Organization setting** -->**Azure Active Directory**. You will see the details whether your org backed with AAD.

[image]

If not, follow this doc to complete connect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

And then, for account, here has two situations:

- **If your personal account is the account which be added in AAD.**

While meet this situation, for you or any other account which has been added into AAD, don't need to do anything like link or migrate. You can still login with your previous personal account and password.

- **Conversely, if the account which be added in AAD is not  your previous personal account and you still want to obtain the data of personal account**.

For this, you need to complete migrate and do identity transfer. Before identity transfer, do not login with the new one account which be added in AAD.

**But**, the identity transfer operation needs to be done from backend by our Microsoft engineer. So, if you have this demand, please contact [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). Meanwhile, offer your account info and AAD info in that ticket, so that our engineer can help you migrate the account data.

Comment: @Robin Are you the member of the AAD which you want to connect it to your org?

Comment: We had to add a new Account temporary to our AAD to do the migration, but it worked. Thank you