# Impact of linking AzureAD to organization domain after persona user creation in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We have many user linked to our company account on Azure DevOps Services. This is done by personal account, with company address. So each user has an email like xxx@mycompany.com

We need to link our domain to an Azure AD. What is the impact on Azure DevOps services?

I can continue using our account or have to be converted to company accounts?

Comment: Hi, How are things going? Please feel free to let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

If the account you are using now is the **same** one which be added in AAD, there will no any impact on your accessing.  Just connect AAD to your org and login with your normal account.

For how to connect, refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

But, if they are **not same**, and also the org has been connect with AAD, you must login with the account which be added into the AAD. If you want data migrate from the previous account, contact Microsoft, our engineer will help you finish identity transfer from back end.

Here is my another answer which I think may help you solve some puzzle: [Change from personal to organizational Account in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56668235/11508165)